# How to integrate ssrs 2008 rdl into Visual studio 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, reportviewer2008

How can I integrate the SSRS 2008 Reportviewer and SSRS 2008 RDL into Visual Studio 2005 (.net 2.0)?

Is there any possibility to use SSRS Report Viewer 2008 in VS 2005(ver 2.0) either direct or using any .msi or using any other component??

Please help me....

Thanks in advance
Shashi

Comment: ReportViewer 2008 is built on .Net 3.5 so I beleive that there is no easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the report viewer web interface if you not running this locally by using the reporting web service. You will use the webbrowser control in your project and display the report right from the report server. This works nicely!

Check this out for the Report, Report Viewer, and Server URL parameters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx